# ajax success function (with html method) only fires once

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm having some problems with ajax callbacks that I'm hoping I could get some help with. Basically, this script replaces the #inbox div with archive.php (which normally would generate messages and matching modals, but for simplicity sake I just included generic modals).

The ajax callback is triggered when you close a modal. It currently returns the modals ID. However, this only works once - that's where I'm having the problem. The problem seems to lie with the jQuery html command. I've replaced it with alert(id) and the script will run as many times as I want. Any suggestions? Please let me know if I need to clarify more. Thanks.

HTML / JavaScript:

```
<div id="inbox"> <!-- Content should be put between this div -->
      <?php include_once('archive.php'); ?>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#inbox .modal').on('hidden', function() {
      id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "archive.php",
          data: {message_id : id},
          cache: false,
          success: function(data) {
            $('#inbox').html(data); // problem is here
          }
        });
    });
  });
</script>
```

PHP (archive.php):

```
<?php echo $_POST['message_id']; // I've also used SQL inserts, which work fine when I'm not using the jQuery HTML command ?>

<!-- Modal 1 -->

<a href="#modalOne" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

<div id="modalOne" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal 2 -->
<a href="#modalTwo" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

<div id="modalTwo" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal 3 (etc...) -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run this:

```
$('#inbox .modal').on('hidden', function() {
```

It finds the current `'#inbox .modal'` objects and binds an event handler to them.

When you then do:

```
$('#inbox').html(data);
```

it replaces those DOM objects with new ones and you no longer have any event handlers active on those new objects.

You have two choices to fix it:

1. You can use delegated event handling which works with dynamically created objects.
2. You can rebind the event handlers after replacing the HTML.

I don't know about the `hidden` event you are using, but if it works with delegated event handling, then you can change to this to use delegated event handling:

```
$('#inbox').on('hidden', '.modal', function() {
```

Here, the event is bound to the `#inbox` object which is not recreated and it then checks events that bubble up to see if they originated on a `.modal` object.  That's how delegated event handling works and it works with child objects that are dynamically created after the event handler is installed on the parent object.

Answer (score 1):

You have bound the event to `$('#inbox .modal')`, so when you replace the content with `$('#inbox').html(data)` you are also removing (replacing) the element that the event is bound to. Instead try `$('#inbox').on('hidden', '.modal', function() {` for binding your event.